# Dynamic EF Query

Tags: entity-framework

I am thinking of designing a business rule engine which basically generates an EF query from a set of string values stored in a database.

For e.g. I will store the connection string, table name, the where condition predicate, and select predicate as string fields in a db and would like to construct the EF query dynamically. For e.g.

```
var db = new DbContext(“connectionstring”);

var wherePredicate = Expression.FromString(“p => p.StartDate > new DateTime(2014,5,1))
var selectPredicate = Expression.FromString(“p => p”)

var results = db.Set(“Projects”).Where(wherepredicate).Select(selectPredicate)
```

For constructing the predicates I can use DynamicExpression or Dynamic LINQ library.

However how do I access db.Set(“Projects”) where Projects is the entity name and apply the where and select predicates? (or something like `db[“Projects”].Where().Select`).

I tried the non-generic version of the `DbContext.Set(Type entityttype)` method, however couldn’t figure out how to apply `Where` and `Select` predicates to the returned object.

I am trying to avoid generating SQL queries and instead rely on dynamically generated EF code.

Comment: Seems like you would be losing all the benefits of the entity-framework.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make much sense. You can create method that will work on `string` instead of generic type using reflection, but you'd have to return `DbSet` not `DBSet<T>`. And on that one you cannot execute LINQ's methods (basically), because there's no type (during compilation). Of course you can do it all the way using reflection, but then, why??? You're loosing 90% of what **O**/R mapper does for you.